# Inline css in the Laravel mailer for email views

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, view

I'm using laravel layouts and templating language for my email views, I need to Inline the css of this emails when sending them using a library like:

https://github.com/christiaan/InlineStyle

I tried manipulating the view writing a view composer for the email views but using view composers the view is not rendered yet so you can not change the rendered result, I even tried manipulation the message object used in the Mail::send but the message does not have a body till its sent, do you have any idea how to implement this behavior?

Comment: I just did a search and came up with this... https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner